# Do C# extension methods affect the current instance or return a new object of the same type?

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

When you extend a non-static type with an extension method, does the work performed on "this" happen to the original instance of the extended class, or does it return a new instance with those changes applied?  Or can it do either, depending on how the extension method is written?

Consider this example extension method:

```
public static AddressEntity FromAddressLight(this AddressEntity addressEntity, AddressLight addressLight)
{
    if (addressLight == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var result = new AddressEntity
    {
        Id = addressLight.AddressId,
        AddressName = addressLight.AddressName,
        // other mapping conversions here
    };

    return result;
}
```

Which of the following ways of calling this would work?

```
AddressLight light = new AddressLight(); // assume constructor populates this
AddressEntity myEntity = new AddressEntity(); // this constructor does not populate anything

myEntity.FromAddressLight(light); // Will this cause myEntity take on the value of "result" in the extension method?...
myEntity = myEntity.FromAddressLight(light); // ... or is this needed to copy "result" into myEntity?

// ... and why is this not something Visual Studio allows? Does this not become a static member of the extended class?
myEntity = AddressEntity.FromAddressLight(light);
```

Comment: obj.ext(arg) is simply syntax sugar for ext(obj, arg), nothing more.

Comment: `AddressEntity.FromAddressLight(light);` cannot be allowed - what would be the value of `this AddressEntity addressEntity`?

Comment: @Hans: Nearly.  It's syntactic sugar for: `NamespaceIUsed.ClassNameThatIDontHaveToRemember.ext(obj, arg)`

Comment: The compiler should definitely put those names in for debugging purposes :)

Comment: Note that VB.NET does allow the `this` argument to be `ref`, so if you used VB.NET you could allow your `ByRef addessEntity` to be changed with say `addressEntity = result` before also returning it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats kind of odd as an extension method (makes more sense as a "normal" static method) but here goes, In order of your lines (skipping the first two):

1. This will do nothing. The extension method returns a new object, which is not assigned to anything, and so falls out of scope and is garbage collected.
2. This will do exactly what you think, and is the only "reasonable" way to use this method.
3. This isn't allowed because there is no instance of "AddressEntity" being passed to the function. Not explicitly (obviously you only pass 1 argument) or implicitly (because you used the type to access it, not an object).

Especially because you are trying to do (3), I would not have this function as an extension method (it doesn't even use any of the AddressEntity field, so why does it take that type?) and have it be a normal static method instead.

To answer your question (in the title) explicitly:

An extension method isn't anything special, it just has an implicit argument (the "this" argument) so it looks nice when calling it. If it returns a new value, you'll get a new value. If you modify the "this" argument, it modifies the existing value. It could actually do both with no problem. It completely depends on the content of the extension method.

Comment: Note on 3: it will be (and already is) a static method of the class where it's found, NOT the type of the `this` parameter.

Comment: Every answer here has been very helpful.  I specifically checked this one as correct because it led me to the "aha" moment (or perhaps "duh" moment) that you can reference "this" inside of the method in order to operate on the calling instance instead of returning a new one.  That was my specific question.  However, all of the design discussion was very helpful in bringing me to a solution.

Answer (score 5):

Quick Answer... It Depends.

The example you give returns a new instance of `AddressEntity` but there's no reason it can't return the same instance which is handy for chaining or something completely different.

It's up to you.

`myEntity = myEntity.FromAddressLight(light);` is the correct use of this method in your example.

And `myEntity = AddressEntity.FromAddressLight(light);` doesn't work because you're calling a static method not an instance method even though this is a little counter-intuitive given the static declaration.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty odd as an extension method, in general. Consider that the extension method is just syntactic sugar (as was previously mentioned by others), and that a normal user would really be expecting one of two things to happen:

1. I call the extension method and get a modified version of myself back.
2. I call the extension method and get a converted type back.

I think number two is what you really want:

```
public static AddressEntity ToAddressEntity(this AddressLight obj)
{
    return new AddressEntity
    {
        Id = obj.AddressId,
        AddressName = obj.AddressName,
        // other mapping conversions here
    };
}
```

Remember that extension methods are not based on the return type but on the type specified after `this`. So in this case you can just do `AddressEntity addEntity = SomeAddressLight.ToAddressEntity();`. This is also the reason you don't see the pattern `FromSomething()` in any of the BCL because in the case of an extension method it feels very counterintuitive.

Comment: Indeed, this is essentially what I ended up writing in the end.  I was given instructions by someone more senior on a project to 1) use extension method for the type mapping) and 2) to convert to AddressEntity from AddressLight, using AddressEntity as "this".  Given those stipulations, I created the odd "FromSomething" extension method.  It turns out the directions were unclear and the conversion was indeed supposed to be to AddressEntity from AddressLight using AddressLight as "this". While this answer doesn't pertain to my exact question, it is a very helpful addition to the thread.